# Snaps won't run due to AppArmor Error

Tags: snap, apparmor

I had an issue with BlueMail all of sudden refusing to launch and I determined that AppArmor was at fault (it was denying BlueMail access to my Downloads folder on another drive).  When I was not able to get any assistance from the BlueMail developers, I tried to troubleshoot it on my own and ultimately decided to remove Snapd from my Ubuntu 19.10 system and reinstall it.  After reinstalling it, however, I no longer have a Snap store and I cannot install ANY Snap apps.  Below are the error messages that I am getting in the console:

error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Setup snap "snapd" (5754) security profiles (cannot setup apparmor for snap "snapd": cannot create host snap-confine apparmor configuration: cannot reload snap-confine apparmor profile: cannot load apparmor profiles: exit status 1
apparmor_parser output:
Warning from stdin (line 1): config file '/etc/apparmor/parser.conf' not found
Cache read/write disabled: interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted?
Use --subdomainfs to override.
)
- Setup snap "snapd" (5754) security profiles (cannot create host snap-confine apparmor configuration: cannot reload snap-confine apparmor profile: cannot load apparmor profiles: exit status 1
apparmor_parser output:
Warning from stdin (line 1): config file '/etc/apparmor/parser.conf' not found
Cache read/write disabled: interface file missing. (Kernel needs AppArmor 2.4 compatibility patch.)
Warning: unable to find a suitable fs in /proc/mounts, is it mounted?
Use --subdomainfs to override.
)

Is there anything I can do to repair this without reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch?